# Postgres: don't select the right table row if it has some condition in the join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table structure in my Postgres database schema:

Table: `modifications`

```
|id|  name |status|
|1 | Mod 1 |  3   |
|2 | Mod 2 |  3   |
|3 | Mod 3 |  3   |
```

Table: `modification_statuses`

```
|id|modification_id|status|sent_at|
|1 |       1       |  8   |2022-11-28|
|1 |       1       |  11  |2022-11-29|
|1 |       2       |  8   |2022-11-28|
|1 |       3       |  8   |2022-11-28|
```

I would like to query `modifications` where:

- `modifications.status = 3` and
- `modification_statuses.status = 8` and
- `DATE(modification_statuses.sent_at) = '2022-11-28'` and
- For a given `modification_statuses.status = 11`, filter query to not have `modification_statuses.status = 11`

The output I am expecting is `Mod 2` and `Mod 3`

My current broken SQL is this:

```sql
SELECT modifications.* FROM modifications
JOIN modification_statuses ON modification_statuses.modification_id = modifications.id
WHERE modifications.status = 3
  AND modification_statuses.status = 8
  AND (DATE(modification_statuses.sent_at) = '2022-11-28')
```

Comment: So why are you missing the `modification_statuses.status` condition from your sql query? Is *that* your actual question?

Comment: usually you remove all where clauses and than add one by one to see which of them removes the wanted result

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. a [mcve].)

Comment: My real challenge is I do not want `Mod 1` in the result set because in the join table one of the associated row has status 11 and I want to query the join table based on status = 8 and sent_at fields. Right now my query is returning Mod 1 in the result set. Hope that explains!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to join to the table twice, once with a LEFT JOIN which then filters out rows which succeed at the join:

```
SELECT modifications.* FROM modifications
JOIN modification_statuses ON modification_statuses.modification_id = modifications.id AND modification_statuses.status = 8 AND (DATE(modification_statuses.sent_at) = '2022-11-28')
LEFT JOIN modification_statuses ms2 ON ms2.modification_id = modifications.id AND ms2.status = 11
WHERE modifications.status = 3 and ms2.modification_id is NULL
```

Alternatively, you could use `AND NOT EXISTS (...)` construct that removes the rows which have a match to status 11.